# Azure App Insights - Items missing from application map?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

You will notice that my app is handling 230k calls, which I know are REST http1.1 calls.

My issue is: there are no arrows pointing TOWARDS the circle, only away! as if the requests being handled were "emanating" from the API, which I know is not what's going on. I know for a fact that there is another system, which is also monitored via app insights that calls this one, and its not showing up.

I also know for instance, that the requests don't "drop" from the internet directly to this guy, they are handled by a API Management solution before arriving!

Any ideia of what might be going on?

Comment: 1) is the calling system sending its telemetry to the same AppInsights instance? 2) are you using correlation IDs on the HTTP calls? (distributed tracing)

Comment: 1) no, but that doesn't seem to be an issue for other applications I have running. 2) not explicitly